# "For all those playing at home" - origin of the idiom?

Tags: etymology, idioms

I've been wondering where this idiom comes from and what the original meaning is. My guess is it comes from a radio or television broadcast of some kind of a game, but I haven't been able to confirm it via Google.

Also, is this the only canonical form of the idiom or are there other common forms?

Comment: It's often stated as "For those (of you) playing along at home" too.

Comment: It is probably just a reasonably common turn of phrase. If you Google "for those of you playing along at home", as @KillingTime suggests, you will see plenty of examples. People often try to answer questions themselves when watching quiz shows etc.

Comment: Apparently Thomas Burton was the first to use "playing at home", in the 1820s.  It didn't reappear until it began being used to describe sports teams playing at their "home" field.  This usage quickly swamped others.

Comment: "Playing along at home" appeared in the 60s, with the advent of TV game shows.

Comment: @HotLicks If you post this as an answer with relevant references, I'll be glad to accept it.